# Xcode: No matching function for call to glGenBuffers

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vbo

I'm creating an iOS game using OpenGL and I'm trying to create a Vertex Buffer Object. But when I try to use glGenBuffers, Xcode tells me "no matching function for call to glGenBuffers". I can use other functions flawlessy, and can render using other methods (but tried to use this one because I read it's faster), so I don't know why this function is undefined.

glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns "OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE".

I'm importing "OpenGLES/EAGL.h", "OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h" and "OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h" in my header file.

I tried using the code from http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object

Comment: It probably would help to post the source snippet with your glGenBuffers call.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably error in your parameters. The second parameter has to be pointer to integer. Check it.

Comment: Ah, now it's fixed! I used GLuint* as you said (I was using GLfloat). I could have just checked that on the function-guess pop-up, but I couldn't make it show up before. Thanks, anyway!